# what is the inverse function of 2[x]-x ,where[x] is the floor function?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

- $f(x) = 2[x]-x$,
- $[x]$ is the floor function,
- the domain of the function is $[-1,2]$,
- its codomain is $\Bbb R$
  $$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
  -2-x & \text{if } -1 \leq x < 0 \\
  -x & \text{if } 0 \leq x < 1 \\
  2-x & \text{if } 1 \leq x < 2 \\
  4-x & \text{if } x = 2 \\
  \end{cases}
  $$
  a diagonal line is formed on the graph going downwards from the starting point of the interval to its end where every $y$ has one  $x$ only so it invertible  that  points have the same $y$

how can i do the inverse, with the  floor function involved ?

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to format your question.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Is [x] the floor or ceiling function? Except reading $f(x)=2[x]-x$ I am not able to read your text

Comment: I tried to take everything written into account hope this is more tidy , and it is the floor function @trula

Comment: Thx for the edit i was showing a respresnation for 2[x] but named it f(x) lost focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse is
$$g(x) = 2\lceil x \rceil - x,$$
where $\lceil x \rceil$ is the ceiling function. To prove this, all we need to do is compose them, i.e. examine $f\circ g$ and $g \circ f$, and verify they are the identity.

Suppose $x \in \Bbb{R}$. We wish to show, first, that $(g \circ f)(x) = x$. We have
$$(g \circ f)(x) = 2\lceil 2 \lfloor x \rfloor - x\rceil - 2 \lfloor x \rfloor + x = x \iff \lceil 2 \lfloor x \rfloor - x\rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor.$$
This is indeed the case, since
\begin{align*}
&0 \le x - \lfloor x \rfloor < 1 \\
\implies \, &-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor - x \le 0 \\
\implies \, &\lfloor x \rfloor - 1 < 2\lfloor x \rfloor - x \le \lfloor x \rfloor \\
\implies \, &\lceil 2\lfloor x \rfloor - x \rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor.
\end{align*}
Thus, $(g \circ f)(x) = x$, as required.

We now wish to show $(f \circ g)(x) = x$. This can be done by observing that $g(x) = -f(-x)$ for all $x$, and so
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(x) &= f(g(x)) \\
&= f(-f(-x)) \\
&= -(-f(-f(-x))) \\
&= -g(f(-x)) \\
&= -(g \circ f)(-x) \\
&= -(-x) = x.
\end{align*}
Thus, $f\circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are the identity map. By definition, $g$ is the inverse of $f$.

Comment: I can certainly see how the prove works and very thankful for it  since it explains some stuff that I had confusion regarding but do you have any suggestions to find my way up , like using ∘  to find the inverse not to only prove it

Comment: @lodo I started with the graph, and reflected it in the line $y = x$ to find the graph of the graph of the inverse, then figured out a formula based on that picture. The original graph is a bunch of parallel line segments, beginning at the points $(n, n)$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$, descending at $45^\circ$. Reflecting flipped them up the other way, meaning they would end on $(n, n)$, while still being at an angle of $45^\circ$. I quickly figured that a ceiling function was in order, and could guess the formula from there.

Comment: thx I already have the original graph drawn I will draw the inverse one and try to do the same reasoning from there, I can't up vote yet since this is my first post but you have my thanks and graduated as well as anyone who participated in this discussion

Answer (score 2):

Note that an Invertible function is A **one-one** and **onto** relation between two sets, which means, there is a unique mapping for each element in first set to other element in second set, Here in your case $f(x)=2[x]-x$, it is piece wise defined for different ranges of x

consider

$-1 \leq x < 0$, $y=f(x)=-2-x$ it's range is $(-2,-1]$

now to find inverse of this piecewise function, replace $x$ with $y$

$x=-2-y$

which can be written as $y=-2-x$ whose domain will be $(-2,-1]$

similiarly you can deduce inverse function by considering them piecewise and finding range of them

Comment: This problem was assigned to me for inverse function revision a solution was provided along side it yet i have no idea how it was reached since i could not really figure out how to deal with the floor function ,the answer was inverse -2[-x]-x

Comment: for one one and onto it achieves both in the range provided i would have liked to add a graph but can’t with my reputation

Comment: I will try to use the way you mentioned above to reconstruct a ceil or floor function from the domain and range I get for every interval